# SQL Server - start date and end date from a training data for an employee

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find the start date and end date from a training data for an employee from the below table.

For the Employee Id 58 Start Date need to be 1/12/2016 and end date should be 1/15/2016.

For the Employee Id 2914 Start Date need to be 12/11/2015 and end date should be 12/12/2016.

Please let me know how to achieve this in SQL.

[image]

Comment: Why should end date for ID 58 be 1/15/2016?  There's more training for him in the same room at a later date.  Are you looking for consecutive training?

Comment: you only required the first training date ? How about subsequent dates ?

Comment: I think the OP wants the first training period range for each  employee. If there is a break in days the training has ended although the location throws a wrench in this. This logic would fit the desired results at least @Squirrel I'm on my mobile though. Poorly worded question for sure.

Comment: The main goal is to pay the allowance during the training period. For example the employee 58 is in training from 1/12 to 1/15, again the employee went for training in the same location but from 1/19 to 1/22. planning to calculate the days using the start date and end date.

Comment: Why the training end date is 1/15/2016 while there's NULL training location? Or NULL is actually a training location.

Comment: @Kris This is not clear. Show expected data please.

Comment: We can leave the NULL part, the expected data is like below

Comment: We can leave the NULL part, the expected data need to be like below 
Emp_Id Emp_Name Start Date End Date Training Location
58         John         1/12/2016 1/15/2016 IAH
58         John         1/19/2016 1/22/2016 IAH
58         John         1/25/2016 1/28/2016 MIA
58         John          2/1/2016          2/2/2016   IAH
2914 Levin 12/11/2015 12/12/2015 IAH
2914 Levin 3/14/2016 3/14/2016 IAH
2914 Levin 6/17/2016 6/17/2016 IAH
2914 Levin 9/12/2016 9/13/2016 IAH